# Link pairs of rows based on a condition in a large Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata, data-analysis, network-analysis

I have a dataframe that consists of about 150K observations. The goal is to find pairs of rows if there is a circular reference. I wrote this code below and it does the job on a small dataset, but it is incredibly slow. Can someone help make this code run faster?

The idea here is, if A referenced B and B referenced A, they should be linked.

Example:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['A', 'C', 'D', 'B'], 'c2': ['B', 'D', 'C', 'A'], 'id':[1,2,3,4]})

# I created a "direction" knowing which way it is being referenced 
df_test['direction'] = df_test['c1'] + df_test['c2']

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
    direction_to_serach = row['c2']+row['c1']
    df_test.drop(index, inplace=True)
    for index2, row2 in df_test.iterrows():
        if row2['direction'] == direction_to_serach:
            df_temp = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(row.values).T,pd.DataFrame(row2.values).T], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
            new_df = new_df.append(df_temp)
            df_test.drop(index2, inplace=True)
    if df_test.empty:
        break
```

Comment: When you ask question, take the time to respond to those who try to help you. [Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like a self-[merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) regardless of column order:

```
new_df = df_test.merge(df_test, left_on=['c1', 'c2'], right_on=['c2', 'c1'])
p = np.sort(new_df[['c1_x', 'c2_x']].values)
new_df['pair'] = p[:, 0] + p[:, 1]
new_df = new_df.drop_duplicates('pair')
```

`new_df`:

```
  c1_x c2_x  id_x c1_y c2_y  id_y pair
0    A    B     1    B    A     4   AB
1    C    D     2    D    C     3   CD
```

---

Or if "direction" is needed:

```
df_test['direction'] = df_test['c1'] + df_test['c2']
new_df = df_test.merge(df_test, left_on=['c1', 'c2'], right_on=['c2', 'c1'])
p = np.sort(new_df[['c1_x', 'c2_x']].values)
new_df['pair'] = p[:, 0] + p[:, 1]
new_df = new_df.drop_duplicates('pair')
```

`new_df`:

```
  c1_x c2_x  id_x direction_x c1_y c2_y  id_y direction_y pair
0    A    B     1          AB    B    A     4          BA   AB
1    C    D     2          CD    D    C     3          DC   CD
```

`pair` can be [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)ped if it is unneeded:

```
new_df = new_df.drop('pair', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As my previous answer is very similar than @HenryEcker, I propose you another solution with `networkx`:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_test, 'c1', 'c2', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

cycles = nx.simple_cycles(G)
```

```
>>> for edge in cycles:
        print(edge)
['D', 'C']
['A', 'B']
```

---

You can rearrange your columns `c1` and `c2` and find duplicates:

```
df_test[['c3', 'c4']] = np.sort(df_test[['c1', 'c2']])
```

```
>>> df_test
  c1 c2  id direction c3 c4
0  A  B   1        AB  A  B
1  C  D   2        CD  C  D
2  D  C   3        DC  C  D
3  B  A   4        BA  A  B

>>> df_test.drop_duplicates(['c3', 'c4'])
  c1 c2  id direction c3 c4
0  A  B   1        AB  A  B
1  C  D   2        CD  C  D
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use go through c1 and c2, sort the value pairs and create a string out of it, then use `pd.Categorical` which will give you a unique number for each group:

```
df_test['group'] = pd.Categorical([''.join(sorted(x)) for x in df[['c1', 'c2']].values]).codes

  c1 c2  id  group
0  A  B   1      0
1  C  D   2      1
2  D  C   3      1
3  B  A   4      0
```